# Converting a list of ids to a space-separated ids

Tags: sed, awk

I have a list of ids as follows, and I want to convert them to a space separated ids (see output below)

INPUT:-

```
485238
478892
475507
467737
486413
483571
490005
```

OUTPUT:-

```
485238 478892 475507 467737 486413 483571 490005
```

Comment: That... appears to be the same. Or am I crazy?

Comment: @ChristianTernus - please check now

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

Comment: @ChristianTernus - I tried sed 's#\n# #g' file but it didnt work..how can I run it on a file,lets say test.txt containing above ids

Comment: You want to check the _answer_ to the question linked above, not the things the question asker (unsuccessfully!) tried.

Comment: @ChristianTernus - even i checked that..it doesnt show how to run on a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\n/ /;ta' file
```

But really this is a job for paste:

```
paste -sd\  file
```

N.B. there is a space after the backslash and a space before the file

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`, you can do this:

```
awk '{printf "%s ",$0}' file
485238 478892 475507 467737 486413 483571 490005
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ more test.txt
485238
478892
475507
467737
486413
483571
490005
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' test.txt
485238 478892 475507 467737 486413 483571 490005
```

If you want to send this to a new file:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' test.txt > test2.txt
$ more test2.txt 
485238 478892 475507 467737 486413 483571 490005
```